# Events in failed transactions

Tags: contract-invocation, events, filters

Can anybody say for sure, if the events that occur in failed transactions (i.e. before "throw") will not be logged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it will not be logged because everything gets reverted.  check it yourself :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract token { 

   event ev(uint256 v); 
    function test(uint256 v){ 

        if (v==1){

            ev(v);
            throw;

        }  } }
```

the event ev won't be logged if you send the value 1